# How to get the whole result of Observable.forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to call several http calls, and do some operations after got all responses.

I tried using Observable.forkJoin, it works fine until when some of the calls got error. Seems it will catch the first response error for error handling and lost others. I want a whole list of all requests with status, successfully or fail.

```
const requests: Observable<any>[] = [];
requests.push(...);
requests.push(...);
requests.push(...);

Observable.forkJoin(requests).subscribe(response => {
  ...
}, error => {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `catchError` operator on each of your requests

```
requests.push(...pipe(
  catchError(val => console.log(val))
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .pipe operator in each request while pushing it to array

```
request.pipe(
    catcherror (this.handleerror);
    )

    function handleerror (err){

    }
```